# How to create a list of lists where each sub-list 'increments' as follows: [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]

Tags: python, list

This works but is unwieldy and not very 'Pythonic'. I'd also like to be able to run through different values for 'numValues', say 4 to 40...

```
innerList = []
outerList = []
numValues = 12
loopIter = 0

for i in range(numValues):
    innerList.append(0)

for i in range(numValues):
    copyInnerList = innerList.copy()
    outerList.append(copyInnerList)

for i in range(len(innerList)):
    for j in range(loopIter + 1):
        outerList[i][j] = 1
    loopIter += 1

print(outerList)
```

Comment: hi if your code works and you ask for improvement this is not the place, you should post it CodeReview :https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK - thanks @RomainL. I'll use that next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
numValues = 12
result = [ [1] * i + [0] * (numValues - i) for i in range(1, numValues+1) ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this as a nested list comprehension, with two iterators over `range(numValues)` and only setting a `1` when the second iterator is `<=` the first:

```
numValues = 4

outerList = [[1 if j <= i else 0 for j in range(numValues)] for i in range(numValues)]
print(outerList)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

If numpy is an option, this can be done *very* easily with [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html):

```
import numpy as np

n=5
out = np.ones((n,n))
np.tril(out)

array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a little bit more intuitive using a matrix approach with numpy.

```
numValues = 5
my_array = np.eye(numValues)
```

it results in

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

From this matrix you can see that the only think you need to do is to sum the rows

```
sol =  [np.sum(mat[:i], axis=0) for i in range(numValues+1)][1:]
```

and you get

```
 [array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]),
 array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])]
```

Answer (score 1):

An useful feature is multiplying lists

```py
>>> [1] * 3
[1, 1, 1]
```

You can put this in a for loop and add the needed 0.
You can imagine a function like this

```py
def sublists(number: int) -> list:
  """
  Creates sub lists which increases by one
  """
  result = []
  for i in range(number):
    sub_list = [1] * (i + 1) + [0] * ( number - i - 1)
    result.append(sub_list)
  return result
```

Then you can call the function

```py
>>> sublists(4)
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```